# Looking for a short story about a man walking on an alien road at night, stalked by some unseen alien animal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I think this is probably a golden age short story by a notable author that I read in the 1970's in an anthology.  Set on an alien planet colonized by earth men.  A man is walking alone on a road at dusk or night.  I can't remember if he set out on foot or his vehicle broke down.  The road winds through mountains or hills or valleys.  He knows it is unsafe to walk this road at night (others have disappeared here?), and he is angry at himself for getting a late start.  About midway, he senses that he is being stealthily stalked by something.  Some dangerous alien animal in the brush?  Can he keep his wits about him, not panic, and make it to safety?  He may or may not have a weapon.  I don't remember how the story ends.  I want to read it again so bad.  It was very suspenseful, just one character, detailing his thoughts throughout the journey.  Reminiscent of Bradbury's The Ravine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like [Arthur C. Clarke's "A Walk in the Dark"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56750). It is by a notable author, was written before the 1970's, and has appeared in many anthologies. There is only one character. His vehicle broke down and he regretted the "lateness of his departure".

A [review of it on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1769944725?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) summarizes it as so:

> Stuck on a dark planet, having to make a risky, lightless walk back to camp, our protagonist has to contend with memories of terrifying stories told over drinks. What sort of things lurk in the dark, on this seemingly silent, dark world? The suspense rises slowly, and just when you think he has made it, a chitinous sound clicks in the darkness...

An [answer to a different question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73337/31936) describes the same story.

You can [read it on baen.com](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781451639414/9781451639414___2.htm).

Comment: That's the one I thought of reading the description.

Comment: Yes!  That is the story.  Thank you so very, very much.  You have made my day!  I never imagined anyone would recognize the story from my fuzzy recollection.  I've printed a copy to read tonight.  I want to savor it because I was certain I'd never read it again.  Just skimming the first page, I'm seeing details I hesitated to include because I thought they may have been remembered from other stories (that it was urgent man reach the neighboring town to catch a ship off world).  You are the best!  Thanks for taking the time to read my question and answer it.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for accepting my answer. Just to let you know, I've closed your question as a duplicate of the other question that asks for the same story. This doesn't mean anything is wrong with your question, it's just a way for us to link the questions together to help anyone else find the same story if they are searching for it. Enjoy the story!

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the checked mark next to your answer.  I am glad I can give positive feedback for your help.  The check is green now, so I guess that means my feedback was accepted.  I so appreciate your help.  I can't believe anyone could sift out all the misremembered parts of my description and identify the story so quickly from the few bits that were accurate.  And thanks so much for directing me to a copy of the story online.  I am going to enjoy re-reading this tonight so very much.  What a great website.

Comment: @Tim I'm glad you've had a good experience with this website! Many of the users here are very good at identifying stories, especially when the description of the story is as good as yours!